# What exactly is the difference between @parallel and pmap?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

As the title states: what exactly is the difference between `@parallel` and `pmap`? I don't mean the obvious one's a macro for a loop and the other works on functions, I mean how exactly does their implementation differ and how should I use this knowledge to choose between them?

The reason I ask is that a lot of the applications I write could use either construct: I could write a loop and calculate something with `@parallel`, or wrap what would have been in the loop into a function and call `pmap` on that. I have been following the advice of using `@parallel` for things which are quick to evaluate and `pmap` for calls where each task takes much longer (as it states in the documentation), but I feel that if I have a better understanding of what it's doing I'd be able to make better choices.

For example: does `@parallel` divide up the work before evaluating? I noticed that if I run a parallel loop where each inner call takes a random amount of time, `@parallel` can take a long time because at the end I have very few processes still working. `pmap` on the same microtests doesn't seem to have this: is `pmap` re-distributing the work as needed?

Other questions like this all stem from my ignorance of what exactly how `pmap` differs from `@parallel`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@parallel` will take the jobs to be done and divy them up amongst available workers **right away**.  Note in the `?@parallel` we get `The specified range is partitioned ... across all workers.`  `pmap` by contrast, will start each worker on a job.  Once a worker finishes with a job, it will give it the next available job.  It is similar to queue based multiprocessing as is common in python, for instance.  Thus, it's not so much a case of "redistributing" work but rather of only giving it out at the right time and to the right worker in the first place.

I cooked up the following example which I believe illustrates this.  In this somewhat silly example, we have two workers, one of which is slow and the other of which is twice as fast.  Ideally, we would want to give the fast worker twice as much work as the slow worker.  (or, more realistically, we would have fast and slow jobs, but the principal is the exact same).  `pmap` will accomplish this, but `@parallel` won't.

For each test, I initialize the following:

```
addprocs(2)

@everywhere begin
    function parallel_func(idx)
        workernum = myid() - 1 
        sleep(workernum)
        println("job $idx")
    end
end
```

Now, for the `@parallel` test, I run the following:

```
@parallel for idx = 1:12
    parallel_func(idx)
end
```

And get back print output:

```
julia>  From worker 2:  job 1
    From worker 3:  job 7
    From worker 2:  job 2
    From worker 2:  job 3
    From worker 3:  job 8
    From worker 2:  job 4
    From worker 2:  job 5
    From worker 3:  job 9
    From worker 2:  job 6
    From worker 3:  job 10
    From worker 3:  job 11
    From worker 3:  job 12
```

It's almost sweet.  The workers have "shared" the work evenly.  Note that each worker has completed 6 jobs, even though worker 2 is twice as fast as worker 3.  It may be touching, but it is inefficient.

For for the `pmap` test, I run the following:

```
pmap(parallel_func, 1:12)
```

and get the output:

```
From worker 2:  job 1
From worker 3:  job 2
From worker 2:  job 3
From worker 2:  job 5
From worker 3:  job 4
From worker 2:  job 6
From worker 2:  job 8
From worker 3:  job 7
From worker 2:  job 9
From worker 2:  job 11
From worker 3:  job 10
From worker 2:  job 12
```

Now, note that worker 2 has performed 8 jobs and worker 3 has performed 4.  This is exactly in proportion to their speed, and what we want for optimal efficiency.  `pmap` is a hard task master - from each according to their ability.

Thus, the recommendations in the Julia docs make sense.  If you have small simple jobs then it is more likely that these issues with`@parallel` won't cause problems.  For bigger or more complex jobs though, `pmap` has advantages.

Comment: Note in Julia 1.0 `@parallel` has been replaced by `@distributed` so you will need to change the code above to get it to work. Also many functions are in the `Distributed` package so this needs to be loaded.