# Optimizing parallel for loop returning array in Julia

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia

I have to calculate a result of an stochastic algorithm multiple times. In the end I want to have all results in an array. The executions of the algorithm are independent of one another. In Julia this can be parallelized easily with a parallel for-loop like this:

```
@parallel (vcat) for i=1:10
    rand() # or any other algorithm yielding a number
end
```

But it seems a little inefficient if one thread gets the result of another thread and the two results are merged after every iteration of the for loop.
Is this correct? In this case, it could be that one thread yields a 100-element array and another one has a 200-element array and these arrays are merged into a 300-element array?
Could I somehow prevent this and rewrite the above code to prevent multiple array allocations and maybe put the result that is calculated inside the for-loop into a pre-allocated array?
Or can I make the reduction operator smarter somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pmap` for this.  It can distribute the work in parallel over your workers, and then store the results of each job as a separate element in an array.  You can then combine this array at the end.

Consider this example, where each job is to create a random vector of differing length, all of which are combined at the end:

```
addprocs(3)

Results = pmap(rand, 1:10)

Result = vcat(Results...)  ## array of length 55.
```

`pmap` will assign each worker a job as soon as it finishes the job it is working on.  As such, it can be more efficient than `@parallel` if your jobs are of variable length. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846838/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-parallel-and-pmap/37849587#37849587) for details).

The `...` syntax breaks the elements of `Results` (i.e. the 10 vectors of varying length) into separate arguments to feed to the `vcat` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know `pmap`. The link to your other answer was also very helpful!